# Is it okay to drop had/ the past perfect if it's already been used in the previous line(s)?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Example sentence:

> Mark, unlike Mary's previous exes, **had suggested** they only meet on weekends. “Everything in moderation," **were his words.**

As you can see the had/perfect past has been dropped in the second sentence. Instead of **had been his words**, there's **were his words**.

Is it okay to drop had/the past perfect if it's already been defined in the previous sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend changing tenses like that. The past perfect indicates that the narration is framed in past tense, and is now referring to something that happened in the past of the past. Lines in past tense happened at time *-x* while lines in past perfect had happened at time *-x-y*:

> Mark, unlike Mary's previous exes, **had suggested** they only meet on weekends. “Everything in moderation," **had been** his words.
>
> ***or:*** Mary even **felt** resentful toward Mark.  Mark, unlike Mary's previous exes, **had suggested** they only meet on weekends. Thinking back, she **remembered** their first date.  “Everything in moderation," **had been** his words.

(felt, remembered at time *-x*; had been, had suggested at time *-x-y*)

Note that in less formal usage, even native speakers may mix up these tenses. The most common alternative is to avoid past perfect altogether and say everything in past tense. It would be a bit unusual to use past perfect in one sentence and then switch to the past-only style in the very next sentence.

Comment: This seems utterly wrong to me. I don't know if you're a native speaker, but as you say in less formal usage the tenses would commonly be mixed. The context appears to be fiction set in the present day, so slight informality is expected and switching tenses is fine. Additionally in this example, "were" is particularly justified because they remained his words (and opinion) after he said them.